# Error in my jsp file: TypeError: $.browser is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jsp-tags

I get this error on my jsp page.
After searching some possible answers on this site, I decided to include the following script tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

However, I now get this warning on page load:

> JQMIGRATE: jQuery is not compatible with Quirks Mode

and I again get the browser undefined error.

These are the following jQuery script tags that I have included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/page/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/dealerActions/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now, my jsp page does start this way:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="com.bluestar.core.logger.ApplicationLogger"%>
<%@page session="true" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*,javax.portlet.*" %>
```

Since I have included doctype at the start, I shouldn't be getting the "Quirks mode" warning. What should I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the following DOCTYPE in your web page:

Modern browsers (Android 1+, Chrome 1+, IE 6+, iOS 1+, Firefox 1+, Netscape 6+, Opera 6+, Safari 1+) would interpret this in the following fashion:

Because there is a correctly written DOCTYPE, this triggers standards mode.
It's an HTML 4.01 Transitional document
Because it's in standards mode, most browsers will render the content compliant (or mostly compliant) with HTML 4.01 Transitional
And if you put this DOCTYPE in your document:

This tells modern browsers that you want to display your HTML 4.01 page in strict compliance with the DTD. These browsers will go into "strict" or "standards" mode and render the page in compliance with the standards. (So, for this document, tags such as  might be completely ignored by the browser, as the FONT element has been deprecated in HTML 4.01 Strict.)

so you need simply change your doctype to HTML5 standard.

by the way jquery-ui.min.js and jquery-ui.js is same except their size and layout so please get rid of this line :

Comment: +1Thanks! This helped resolve the Quirks mode error!
However, the browser not defined error still persists inspite of using migrate.

Answer (score 1):

accroding to http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

`jQuery.browser()` removed

The `jQuery.browser()` method has been deprecated since `jQuery 1.3` and is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the `jQuery Migrate plugin`. We recommend using feature detection with a library such as Modernizr.

If you still need this function, you can get one js file from: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin
and link the js to your file.